# Find market company names from FinancialData

Tags: curated-data, finance

Is there a way to get code names of publicly traded companies by any FinancialData option?
I would like to identify for each market the company listed there and to associate it with the code name in order to filter companies according to some parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by "code name". Perhaps,

```
prop = {"Name", "StandardName", "Symbol", "CIK", "SICCode"};

Grid[Join[{prop}, FinancialData[#,
     prop] & /@ {"Alphabet", "Microsoft", "Apple"}],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
all = FinancialData[];

exch = StringCases[all, __ ~~ ":"] // Union // Flatten

(* {"DE:", "F:", "HK:", "L:", "MB:", "NASDAQ:", "NYSE:", "PA:", 
    "SS:", "SZ:", "TO:", "TSE:"} *)

nasdaq = FinancialData["NASDAQ:*"];

consumerElec = Select[nasdaq,
   FinancialData[#, "Sector"] === "ConsumerElectronics" &];

Length /@ {all, nasdaq, consumerElec}

(* {46311, 2926, 9} *)
```

Comment: Thank you Bob, with "code name" I mean what you called "StandardName", but is there a way to have a similar list with all the companies of the world or of a market without writing every time the name of each company within &/{"Microsoft","Apple",...}?

Comment: @Mick Are you looking for `FinancialData[]`, `FinancialData["NASDAQ:*"]`, ...

Comment: Thank you guys, that's what I was looking for! How can I associate "Standard Name" for each market to "Name" of the company?

Comment: Do not ask new questions in comments. You should have enough information now to formulate a clear question to include a minimal example, the code that you have tried, and what specific problems you are having with the code.

Comment: Got it, thank you

Comment: Can you help me please with this other question?https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219864/conditions-on-financialdata