# Conditions on FinancialData

Tags: curated-data, finance

I would like to order (3) on a Dataset or Table all the Financial Data between all markets respecting those constraints:

- each asset has to be shown as "Name" and "StandardName";
- I would like to show "Price" and "MarketCap" for each company if required with the option to filter companies by “MarketCap”;
- show **(1) stock income** (I suppose it is equal to EarningPerShare/Price properties)
- show **(2) Return Of Capital % values** (I don't know how to calculate it by using FinancialData properties);
- order companies for (1) and (2) indexes separately;
- sum the position of (1) and (2) for each company, in order to have a final list (3) which I look for.

This is what I've done and what I suppose to do:

```
ex = FinancialData["Exchange", "Lookup"];
assets = FinancialData[#, "Lookup"] & /@ ex;
names = FinancialData[assets, "Name"];
codes = FinancialData[assets, "StandardName"];
prices = FinancialData[assets, "Price"];
capital = FinancialData[assets, "MarketCap"];
EPS = FinancialData[assets, "EarningsPerShare"];
RPS = EPS/prices // PercentForm;
ROI = … 
t1=Sort[{names,codes,prices,RPS,ROI},RPS]
t2=Sort[{names,codes,prices,RPS,ROI},ROI]
t3=...
```

Comment: Questions should be pared to minimal examples. For example, `assets = FinancialData[#,"Lookup"][[1;;10]]& /@ ex;` would presumably represent what you want. In order to compare across exchanges, all price related values need to be in a common currency, e.g., `prices = (If[FreeQ[#, Missing], UnitConvert[#, "Dollars"], #]& /@ FinancialData[assets, "Price"];` You need to define what is meant by `stock income` and `Return Of Capital % values` rather than require us to guess. The sorts should be structured like `t1 = SortBy[Transpose[{names, codes, prices, RPS, ROI}], #[[4]]&]`